# How to make auto-indent XML in vim?

Tags: indentation, markup, filetype-xml

I am thinking on a similar solution, which Eclipse also does: during the editing, the editor tries to always hold in a "well-indented" format of the edited textual data.

Ideally, it would happen very strong: the best were if anything breaking the well-formatting would be corrected on the spot.

Is it somehow possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I commented out my entire .vimrc file, then added a few indentation related things. Using the process of elimination, I landed on the following line being solely responsible getting my XML indentation to work:

```
filetype plugin indent on
```

However, this only worked when loaded from the .vimrc file. Manually typing it in had no effect for me.

According to `:h filetype-indent-on`:

> You can enable loading the indent file for specific file types with:
>          :filetype indent on
>
> If filetype detection was not switched on yet, it will be as well.
>   This actually loads the file "indent.vim" in 'runtimepath'.
>   The result is that when a file is edited its indent file is loaded (if there
>   is one for the detected filetype). |indent-expression|

If you have `filetype indent on` enabled in your .vimrc and don't have indentation, you're probably missing the indentation definition file.

Comment: Additionally, you may or may not need to `set nocompatible` in your .vimrc file. It's generally good practice to set it unless you absolutely need vi compatibility.